# Browser compatibility of console JavaScript

Tags: javascript, logging, console

I am using `console.log`, `console.debug`, `console.info` and `console.warn`. I din't find any notice about the browser compatibility of this console-function. Which browser do exactly support what kind of console-methods?

Comment: Here you go: [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log#Browser_compatibility), [`console.info`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.info#Browser_compatibility), [`console.warn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.warn#Browser_compatibility). Don't know about `console.debug`. Basically FF4+, IE8+ and any other browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the browser compatibility in the MDN website:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log

Not all browser supports all of the methods you mentioned.